# PHP script processing all lines of a file twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that generates an HTML form for users to upload a file.  I save that file on the server using `move_uploaded_file` then read it using `fgets()` and perform database inserts based on certain check.  Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
$cart_id = 18566;
if (empty($_POST))
{
  echo "<form name=\"upload\" action=\"myscan.php\" id=\"myScan\" method=\"POST\"  enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
  echo "Choose the file to upload:<br>\r\n";
  echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"300000\" form=\"myScan\" />";
  echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" form=\"myScan\" id=\"fileUp\"  /><br>";
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\" name=\"sub\" form=\"myScan\" />";
  echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ck\" form=\"myScan\" value=\"".$cart_id."\" />";
  echo "</form><br>";
}
else
{
  // link to cart goes here
}

$fname = "1SCAN20131031123456";
if (!empty($_POST))
{
  $allowedExts = array("txt", "csv");
  $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
  if ( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain" 
      || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    && array_search(strtolower($extension), array_map('strtolower', $allowedExts)) !== FALSE )
  {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."<br>";
      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
      else
      {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $fname);
        echo "Moved to: " . $fname . "<br>";
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Extension: " . $extension . "<br>\n";
}
```

At this point the file `$fname` is ok, no duplicated lines.  The next part is called as a function declared in the same PHP file.  `$link`, `$fname`, and `$cart_id` are declared as globals

```
$bn = basename($fname);
$sfd = fopen($fname, "r");
$store_number = "$bn[0]";
if(is_numeric($bn[1]))
  $store_number .= $bn[1];
$a = stripos($bn, "SCAN");
$a += 4;
$dt = substr($bn, $a);
//  echo "Date = $dt \n";
$fy = substr($dt, 0, 4);
$fM = substr($dt, 4, 2);
$fd = substr($dt, 6, 2);
$fh = substr($dt, 8, 2);
$fm = substr($dt, 10, 2);
$fs = substr($dt, 12, 2);
$fdate = "$fy-$fM-$fd $fh:$fm:$fs";
//  echo $fname . ",";
//  echo $store_number . ",";

while ($line = fgets($sfd))
{
  $li = explode(",", $line);
  if (sizeof($li) == 5)
  {
    $scan = $li[0];
    $poQty = $li[1];
    $cntQty = $li[2];
    $limd = $li[3];
    $lihms = $li[4];
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload_datalog (file_name, store, filedate, scan, po_qty, cnt_qty, scan_md, scan_hms, cart_id)\n"
    . "VALUES (\"$bn\", $store_number, \"$fdate\", \"$scan\", $poQty, $cntQty, \"$limd\", \"$lihms\", $cart_id)";
  mysqli_query($link, $query);
  }
  else if ($fM < 8 || ($fM == 8 && $fd < 16 ))
  {
    $scan = $li[0];
    $poQty = $li[2];
    $cntQty = $li[1];
    $limd = $li[3];
    $lihms = $li[4];
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload_datalog (file_name, store, filedate, scan, po_qty, cnt_qty, scan_md, scan_hms, cart_id)\n"
    . "VALUES (\"$bn\", $store_number, \"$fdate\", \"$scan\", $poQty, $cntQty, \"$limd\", \"$lihms\", $cart_id)";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
  }
  else if (sizeof($li) == 3 && $li[0] != "" && $li[1] != "" &&$li[2] != "" )
  {
    $scan = $li[0];
    $poQty = $li[2];
    $cntQty = $li[1];
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload_datalog (file_name, store, filedate, scan, po_qty, cnt_qty)\n"
    . "VALUES (\"$bn\", $store_number, \"$fdate\", \"$scan\", $poQty, $cntQty)";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
  }
}
fclose($sfd);
```

The file contains this information:

This all works more than 99 percent of the time, but twice in the past 2 weeks, the entries in the `upload_datalog` table have been duplicated.  There is another function after this that also reads the file and performs inserts based on different checks, and those are duplicated as well.

I know this is an edge case, but I couldn't find any information as to why this would happen on php.net or through google, and I have not been able to reproduce it mysqlf. But I know it occurs in the wild.

Is there a race condition I'm not seeing here?

Comment: are you reading a csv file and parsing it, after user uploads it? does your uploader meant to accept csv file only or other files also? if it's csv, can you post some sample data to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Yes, after the user uploads, I copy the file, then read and parse it.  I have attempted to write it such that a *.csv or *.txt file will work.  Here's an example of the input file.  http://pastebin.com/niuLXwwX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do your inserts in a while loop, so you run twice through that loop? 
For debugging, add a counter in your loop and create a small debug function, and a debug table. Insert the counter and data in your debug table. Compare these values with your expectations

Comment: yes, `while (fgets($sfd))` is a loop, but all tests are mutually exclusive... `if(){...}else if(){...}else if(){...}` which means only one or none of the inserts should occur, right?

Comment: In your loop the tests are exlusive, just 1 of them will be executed. But you get 2 inserts, so the only way possible is the loop running twice. I cant say what is happening, i just say, check what is happening and build that little testtool. You need to check what is going on, else you keep guessing

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think you are right in that I will have to write a check and when the error occurs dump every variable to a file for a postmortem.  This will be the only way I can track down what is causing the problem.